# SynPS/2 Synaptic Touchpad gone crazy

Tags: touchpad, mouse, lenovo

I recently installed elementaryOS on Lenovo B50-45 laptop, the arrow of the SynPS/2 Synaptic touchpad moves on its own and the touchpad seems to be used by two people at once. No it's not a ghost . Hope someone can help me  thanks.

Tried to install gpointing-device-settings

Tried to edit xinput properties

Tried to update and upgrade softwares and system

don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Once you had installed `gpointing-device-settings`, did you actually use it? I'm not sure how you'd go about translating them, but the instructions in [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1619040&p=10106902#post10106902) are quite likely to fix the problem you're encountering. It strikes me that the problem you face is that your drivers are not right for your hardware. Take a look, see what you can work out. If you don't make any progress let me know what you've tried in a comment and I'll install on my old Lenovo laptop to see if I can reproduce it.